# NW.js Iframe fails to load some https website due to net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH error with flags

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

Using NW.js, trying to get iframe to load `https://asdf.com` and instead I get `net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`. I asked on the nw.js mailing list but there seems to be no guide to this bug.

here's my package.json with chromium flags set to ignore any certificate issue. I am out of ideas as to what else to pursue here.

```
{
    "name": "browser",
    "chromium-args": "--enable-file-cookies --allow-running-insecure-content --ignore-certificate-errors",      
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "An example of using a local webserver in NW.js",
    "repository": "https://github.com/TheJaredWilcurt/nw-local-server",
    "node-main": "server.js",
    "main": "http://localhost:3000",
    "node-remote": "http://localhost:3000",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nw ."
    },
    "author": "The Jared Wilcurt",
    "license": "MIT",
    "devDependencies": {
        "nw": "^0.12.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.17.1"
    }
}
```

here's my `index.html`, I tried without the nwfaketop as well, it still fails.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page</title>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <iframe src='https://asdf.com' nwfaketop nwdisable></iframe>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this comes from a mismatch of running the browser on an HTTP url (localhost) and loading HTTPS content inside it. If that is the case, there are two options:

- Don't use a local server for your app, just point directly to `index.html` as your `main` instead of `http://localhost:3000`
- Manually set up HTTPS certificates locally:

  - https://medium.com/@nitinpatel_20236/how-to-create-an-https-server-on-localhost-using-express-366435d61f28

Comment: I opened file:///C:/myproject/index.html directly but I get the same error message. Wish there was another way to do this since I am going to be distributing my nw.js app, I don't want the end user to have to "fix" it on their end. Is there another way of doing this? Will I need to distribute my SSL certificates? Not sure why its still failing when I load the file directory without the server. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Yup I got https://localhost to load but when I navigate to https://asdf.com it still fails